# Which OTP (one-time password) algorithm do banks use on their password generator token?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords, onlinebanking

Many banks offer some token devices in order to create passwords for one time usage. I wonder which OTP algorithm they use? Is it HOTP or TOTP?

Comment: Surely that might differ based on the bank involved? I don't think there's a *single* standard used by every bank on the planet, so this question can't really be answered. (If it is, I'd like to see a credible source for the information cited along with the answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As aiodintsov said, the answer cannot be generalized but the choice of technology really depends upon the bank. My guess is `TOTP`. But let me give a reason on the choice.

*TOTP removes the need for client and server to stay in sync on the event counter by using a Unix timestamp instead. The algorithm allows the server to choose how far off an incoming timestamp it deems acceptable, in order to correct for clock drift.*

When you receive an OTP from a bank, it will usually say that you should use that OTP within certain timelimit after which it will expire. If the banks use `HOTP`, the OTPs neednot expire after a time interval rather it will expire only after you place another request, incrementing the counter.

So, next time you receive a OTP which does not ask you to use it within a timelimit, be sure it is generated using `HOTP`.

Comment: Nice justification!
Since there is a time limit for keying in the password as you said they should implement system clock-based.
Thanks for your thoughtful reply.

Answer (score 2):

They may use whatever they want, any hash function of their choice. Both HOTP and TOTP are used. see RFC 4226 and RFC 6238. I once had a test card with HOTP algorithm in complete accordance with RFC 4226 and could use it for authentication solution (the secret key was provided for the card).